# Different outputs for different python Interpreters

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I was trying to implement a single byte XOR decryption in python. When i run this in **python2.7** I get the desired value
`(88, "Cooking MC's like a pound of bacon")`
But when run in **python3.2** i get
`(0, b'\x1b77316?x\x15\x1b\x7f+x413=x9x(7-6<x7>x:9;76')`

Here is my code.

```
'''
Created on Oct 24, 2015

Matasano Crypto Challenge 3
'''

import binascii
from Crypto.Util.strxor import strxor_c  
from collections import Counter
import math

FREQUENCY_TABLE = {
    b'a':  0.08167,
    b'b':  0.01492,
    b'c':  0.02782,
    b'd':  0.04253,
    b'e':  0.1270,
    b'f':  0.02228,
    b'g':  0.02015,
    b'h':  0.06094,
    b'i':  0.06966,
    b'j':  0.00153,
    b'k':  0.00772,
    b'l':  0.04025,
    b'm':  0.02406,
    b'n':  0.06749,
    b'o':  0.07507,
    b'p':  0.01929,
    b'q':  0.00095,
    b'r':  0.05987,
    b's':  0.06327,
    b't':  0.09056,
    b'u':  0.02758,
    b'v':  0.00978,
    b'w':  0.02360,
    b'x':  0.00150,
    b'y':  0.01974,
    b'z':  0.00074,
}

def englishness(a):
    c = Counter(a.lower())
    total_characters = len(a)
    coefficient = sum(math.sqrt(FREQUENCY_TABLE.get(char, 0) * y/total_characters) for char,y in c.items())
    print (coefficient)
    return coefficient

def answer(s):
    print (s)
    def compfunc(items):
        return englishness(items[1])
    return max([(i, strxor_c(s,i)) for i in range(0,256)], key = compfunc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    encodedS = b'1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736'
    S = binascii.unhexlify(encodedS)
    print (answer(S))
```

I messed around with the code a little bit and found that the englishness() function is not giving the right coefficients in python3.2 (It's always giving 0). I can't figure out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I think the author of the library might be able to answer this in a better way. Seems to be a problem with the pycrypto library.

Comment: @CrakC I dont think it is a problem with the pycrypto library. As shown above the value of "i" for which it is giving the desired result is "88". I opened the Python3.2 Interpreter and strxor_c(S,88) is giving me the correct output string ("Cooking MC's like a pound of bacon"). Besides according to the official site, pycrypto works for Python2.1 through Python3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is problematic

```
coefficient = sum(math.sqrt(FREQUENCY_TABLE.get(char, 0) * y/total_characters) for char,y in c.items())
```

In Python3, `char` is the ord of the character - not the actual character as it is in Python2. Compare:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> [char for char in b'foobar']
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
>>> 

$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jul 28 2015, 18:20:59) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> [char for char in b'foobar']
[102, 111, 111, 98, 97, 114]
```

One quick (ugly) fix is

```
coefficient = sum(math.sqrt(FREQUENCY_TABLE.get(bytes([char]), 0) * y/total_characters) for char,y in c.items())
```

Comment: that actually solved the problem. But can you please tell me the difference between bytes(char) and bytes([char])?

Comment: `bytes(char)` returns an array of char zeros (remember, char is a number here) `bytes(10) == b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Comment: why does it give a different output for a list then? meaning, why does enclosing the number in square brackets give a different value?

Comment: The arguments are interpreted the same as for `bytearray`:https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray